# Can't compile my project with Maven using local repository snapshot

Tags: java, maven, build, compiler-errors, snapshot

I'm trying to execute the command "mvn clean install" on my Java project. Some classes have dependency to a SNAPSHOT project that it's in my local repo.

This is the dependency tag in my project pom

```
<dependency>   
  <groupId>my-package</groupId>  
  <artifactId>project-name</artifactId>   
  <version>3.0.0.0000-SNAPSHOT</version>   
  <scope>compile</scope> 
</dependency>
```

Even though I see there is a jar in my maven local repo called "project-version"-SNAPSHOT.jar maven gives me the error "Compilation Error" on those lines that contains a reference to the snapshot jar.
I tried run the command "mvn -U clean install" but doesn't work; I tryed with mvn dependency:tree and it founds the dependency and finish with a BUILD SUCCESS, so I guess he can find the folder and the file but still prefer to use the older (not SNAPSHOT) version that it gets from my nexus server.

EDIT: I can't creare a release on my nexus server, I need to test the jar before a deploy, never add problems doing so

EDIT 2: I tried to remove the keyword "Snapshot" (try&error approach, I know I shouldn't do that), now it gives me an error more pertinent to my problem

`Could not resolve dependencies for project project-name:pom:3.0.0.0000-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: my-package:project-name-client:jar:3.0.0.0000, my-package:project-name-server:jar:3.0.0.0000: Could not find artifact my-package:project-name-client:jar:3.0.0.0000 in nexus`

Comment: `so I guess he can find the folder and the file but still prefer to use the older (not SNAPSHOT) version that it gets from my nexus server.` You have defined a SNAPSHOT version and not a release version.. as your build fails it means the SNAPSHOT is presumably removed from your repository manager...

Comment: Try to do a `mvn clean install` in your `project-name` project with the snapshot and then try what you have done again.

Answer (score 0):

I post an answer myself in case someone will have the same problem. Apparently if you use IntelliJ is just an IDE bug, to resolve the problem just press right-click on the outer pom file -> Maven -> Reload

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dependency with the "snapshot" version, try compiling while also making the "snapshot" version of the application. It worked for me, I had the same error and couldn't compile.

```
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>project-name</artifactId>
<version>version-SNAPSHOT</version>
....
<dependency>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
  <version>dependency-snapshot-version</version>
</dependency>
```